# java/android - SimpleDateFormat - for hh:mm - remove minutes if 0 minutes

Tags: java

How can I remove :00 for beginning of hour using SimpleDateFormat

```
5:00 PM ----> 5 PM
5:30 PM ----> 5:30 PM
```

I tried `hh:mm`, `h:mm`, `h:m` etc.

Comment: Can you be much more specific? You just want to use one operation or you could allow to use parser? like LocalTime.parse()??

Comment: You will need to make a decision on which formatter to use based on the values from the date object

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple `format` method that uses the appropriate `SimpleDateFormat` instance -- depending on  whether the input `Date` sits at the top of an hour (after rounding to nearest minute).

```
static final SimpleDateFormat F  = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a"); // Eg: "5:30 PM"
static final SimpleDateFormat FH = new SimpleDateFormat("h a");    // Eg: "5 PM"

static String format(Date d) {
    final int mins = d.getMinutes();
    final int secs = d.getSeconds();
    return ((mins == 0 && secs < 30 || mins == 59 && secs >= 30) ? FH : F).format(d);
}
```

[EDITED]

Alternatively, to avoid using the deprecated `getMinutes` and `getSeconds` methods:

```
static String format(Date d) {
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(d);
    final int mins = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    final int secs = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    return ((mins == 0 && secs < 30 || mins == 59 && secs >= 30) ? FH : F).format(d);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that works with leap seconds and so on....? You're probably better off looking at minutes in the hour than seconds since 1970-01-01...

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `Date#getMinutes`?  Seems it would be a more reliable indicator

Comment: Even if there are 0 minutes, there could still be, say, 59 seconds.

Comment: I have updated my answer to round to nearest minute (using `getMinutes` and `getSeconds`) to decide which `SimpleDateFormat` to use.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleTimeFormat.parse will give a Date return. While Date.getMinute() is deprecated and not recommended to use, so another way could set the date into Calendar and use minutes get from calendar to check.
When parsing the time, it would be better to throw the ParseException.
Hope this could help.

```
public static String changeTimeFormat(String timeString) throws ParseException {
            SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
            Date date = null;
            date = sf.parse(timeString);
            if(date != null) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.clear();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                return (calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) == 0)?
                        new SimpleDateFormat("h a").format(date) : timeString;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

If i understood your question, i think there is a way by print it like this: **5 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time** but you need to implement this line **"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz"** instead of **hh:mm** etc. Let me know if this solves your problem or if i missunderstood your question.